# Long equals in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

How could I proceed to make an "equal" arrow in a diagram in tikz? To be clearer, what I would like to obtain is the equivalent of the following command in xy:

> \ar@{=}[direction]

Two examples of what I want (done in tikz):

[image]

and

[image]

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I guess `\draw (a1) edge[bend left,double distance=2pt] (a2);` should work, assuming nodes be named...

Comment: "double distance" works for the equal sign :) Do you know by any chance if there is a way to use something like  "to [out = 45, in = -45]" instead of "bend left"?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use `double equal sign distance` in your `\draw` options to set the distance between the double lines to match that of an equal sign.

The double lines work with any path specification, including things like `bend left` or `to [out=45]`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [double equal sign distance] (0,0) to [out=45, in=180] (3,0) node [anchor=mid west] {$= A$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yours answers rock!

Comment: Although this is right, I want to gripe pointlessly that the `double distance` option always produces a faint dark edge across the "gap" at the ends of the path.  Presumably this is because the path is drawn first in black and then overdrawn in white (as the manual explains) but it would be nice if they would line up correctly...

Answer (score 15):

The great [`tikz-cd`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd) package ([tikz-cd](/questions/tagged/tikz-cd), [manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tikz-cd/tikz-cd-doc.pdf)) includes the option `equal` for arrows.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert=false]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\tikzset{commutative diagrams/.cd,arrow style=tikz,diagrams={>=latex'}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[swap,bend angle=45]
A \dar{f} \rar{a} \ar[bend left,equal]{rr}
  & X \dar{g} \rar{r}
      & A \dar[swap]{f} \\
B \rar[swap]{i}   \ar[bend right,equal]{rr}
      & Y \rar[swap]{\beta}
          & B
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]