# Can't use 'equal' in tikz-cd

Tags: tikz-pgf, texmaker, tikz-cd

Ok, here is the problem. I'm trying to draw some commutative diagram in LaTeX that involve some "equal" sign in `tikz-cd`:

```
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
0 \arrow{r}  & X \ar[equal]{d}\\
0 \arrow{r} & X
\end{tikzcd}
\]
```

(`\usepackage{tikz-cd}` is already included in the preamble)

I get the diagram but **the equal signs appear as simple arrows**. In Kile I get no errors but in TeXMaker the following error appears:

> ! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/equal' and I am
>   going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

By reading some other threads I got the impression that this is "pgf" related problem. I have several TeX related folder in my `/usr/share`:

> texinfo,     texmaker,    texmf,       texmf-dist,  texmf-local

it seems that pgf files are inside `texmf-dist`:

> /usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf

I think that TeXMaker is using this folder too, based on the content of TeXMaker log file:
http://www.ipaste.eu/view.php?id=4065

So what's wrong with the pgf that can't render the "equal sign"?

Comment: Take a look at [an answer of mine](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/121192/16595) where I have used the `equal` arrow, which should render as a line, not an arrow tip. From the log file, I can see that you use an old version of `tikz-cd` (`2012/03/18 v0.2b`). My current version is `2012/12/30 v0.3c`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: @ Qrrbrbirlbel, I still get arrows using your code in that answer. I reckon it's because of the old version. How can I upgrade the current version? Shall I remove the current version first? I've read the {pgfmanual.pdf} and it says just extract the files you download in  texmf/tex/generic/pgf and issue texhash. My current pgf folder is in texmf-dist shall I just install the new version in texmf fodler?

Comment: I first removed /usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf
directory then copying pgf files downloaded from sourceforge and extracting them in the newly created /usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf and then issued the command texhash. the problem still persists. Shall I not compile the pgf package first? does texhash automatically do that (apparently it doesn't)? Please help, I'm already under pressure to finish the paper.

Comment: There is no need to update packages yourself, manually or by removing old files first. Simply use the updating manager from your distribution. Take a look at [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437)

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Based on your comments, is this a dupe? Alternatively, is it simply an 'update your packages' issue? Would be good to close one way or another.

Comment: @JosephWright Yes, yes and yes. “Closed as ‘Why would you want to install packages manually?’”

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an issue which is solved in the latest release, which can be installed by your package manager.