# Using newtxmath with the original arrowheads

Tags: arrows, tikz-arrows, newtxmath

I am using Linux Libertine as a font, and therefore decided to typeset all mathematical formulas with `newtxmath`. I noticed that the package redefines the arrowheads.

However, I am also using `tikz` and `tikzcd`, which use the original arrowheads.

I slightly prefer the original arrowheads with their curly tips. Is there a way to redefine *all* arrows, but keeping the math font from `newtxmath` otherwise?

I checked in the documentation of the package, but couldn't find anything like that...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}

\begin{document}
$A\to B,  a\mapsto b$

\begin{tikzcd}A\arrow[r] & B \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image: Arrow heads with newtxmath]

Comment: Are you familiar with the `old-arrows` package? (Load it after `newtxmath`.)

Comment: One thing you always can do (I think) is to import the standard arrows one by one using [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14388). Hopefully there is some better way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get curly-shaped arrowheads while using the `newtxmath` package, you may want to load the [old-arrows](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/old-arrows) package.

The following screenshots show the output of an MWE without and with the `old-arrows` package loaded.

[image]
[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
%\usepackage{old-arrows} % uncomment as desired
\begin{document}
$A\to B$, $a\mapsto b$, $c\gets d$, $u\leftrightarrow v$
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: Just for completeness, here are a couple of screenshots that show the effect that loading the `old-arrows` package has if no font package is loaded, i.e., if the `Computer Modern` font is employed. The main effect is a noticeable reduction in the *size* of the arrowheads (back to their pre-1992 sizes, according to the user guide of the `old-arrows` package).

[image]
[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
%\usepackage{old-arrows} % uncomment as desired
\begin{document}
$A\to B$, $a\mapsto b$, $c\gets d$, $u\longleftrightarrow v$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi @Mico, this works great! Did you notice that `newtxmath` also changes the size of the arrowheads in `tikz`? Somehow, they got bigger, which cannot be altered by `old-arrows`, apparently.

Comment: @Lukas - I'm afraid I'm not all that familiar with `tikz`. It should be noted that while the `old-arrows` package manages to reintroduce curly-tipped arrowheads, the *size* of the arrowheads is also reduced somewhat.

Comment: Ah ha! That must mean they give *really* old arrows, imitating early Computer Modern arrows from before DEK enlarged the arrowheads (without altering the character bounding boxes, so the new arrows hang out of the box). I liked the originals more.

Comment: @DonaldArseneau - Indeed, the arrowheads produced by the `old-arrows` package are those from pre-1992. Like you, I prefer the older, smaller arrowheads. :-)

Answer (score 4):

Here is how you can adjust the arrows in `tikz-cd`, regardless of whether or not you load `old-arrows` (as suggested in [Mico's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/537588/194703)).  `tikz-cd` comes with the option to get the arrow head from a glyph. So we can just use the `rightarrow` glyph to get

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{old-arrows} % uncomment as desired
\tikzset{
math to/.tip={Glyph[glyph math command=rightarrow]}}
\begin{document}
$A\to B,  a\mapsto b$

\begin{tikzcd}
A\arrow[r,-math to] & B \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

When you comment out the `\usepackage{old-arrows}`

[image]

What if you wish to install this globally for "ordinary" arrows? Just redefine the `rightarrow` style.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
%\usepackage{old-arrows} 
\tikzset{
math to/.tip={Glyph[glyph math command=rightarrow]}}
\tikzcdset{rightarrow/.code={\pgfsetarrows{tikzcd cap-math to}}}

\begin{document}
$A\to B,  a\mapsto b$

\begin{tikzcd}
A\arrow[r] & B \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

You can emulate more and more of these arrows. This essentially amounts to copying the code from `tikzlibrarycd.code.tex` and replacing the arrow heads as described above. Here are a few more.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
%\usepackage{old-arrows} 
\tikzset{
ambient rightarrow/.tip={Glyph[glyph math command=rightarrow]},
ambient Rightarrow/.tip={Glyph[glyph math command=Rightarrow]},
}

\tikzcdset{ambient arrows/.code={
\tikzcdset{rightarrow/.code={\pgfsetarrows{tikzcd cap-ambient rightarrow}},
  Rightarrow/.code={\tikzcdset{double line}\pgfsetarrows{tikzcd implies cap-ambient Rightarrow}},
  leftarrow/.code={\pgfsetarrows{ambient rightarrow-tikzcd cap}},
  Leftarrow/.code={\tikzcdset{double line}\pgfsetarrows{ambient Rightarrow-tikzcd implies cap}},
  leftrightarrow/.code={\pgfsetarrows{ambient rightarrow-ambient rightarrow}},
  Leftrightarrow/.code={\tikzcdset{double line}\pgfsetarrows{ambient Rightarrow-ambient Rightarrow}},
  mapsto/.code={\pgfsetarrows{tikzcd bar-ambient rightarrow}},
  mapsfrom/.code={\pgfsetarrows{ambient rightarrow-tikzcd bar}},
  Mapsto/.code={\tikzcdset{double line}\pgfsetarrows{tikzcd implies bar-ambient Rightarrow}},
  Mapsfrom/.code={\tikzcdset{double line}\pgfsetarrows{ambient Rightarrow-tikzcd implies bar}},
  }}}
\begin{document}
$A\to B,  a\mapsto b,C\Rightarrow D$

\begin{tikzcd}[ambient arrows]
A\arrow[d,mapsto]\arrow[r] & B \\
C & \arrow[l,Rightarrow] D\arrow[u,Rightarrow]
\end{tikzcd} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

One should, however, also mention that, while these glyphs are really great, they are not perfect nor quite as versatile as the arrows from `arrows.meta`. So you should not expect to be able to bend them arbitrarily and your may find viewer-dependent glitches. If you want this, then you probably need to declare arrow heads on your own. This is not particularly difficult but somewhat tedious. For details look up `\pgfdeclarearrow` in the pgf manual (and look for posts using this command). (Ironically a couple of hours ago I believe to have found that the [`Implies` arrow head](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/537544/194703) might be somewhat less versatile than one may think it is.)

Comment: Very kind. If you do a zoom in the last image there are the little edges (the color is gray peraphs). This is a "famous" problem between `tikz-cd` and `tikz`: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/535921/tikz-cd-equal-option-produces-faint-edge-across-gap-at-ends-of-path.

Comment: @Sebastiano Yes, they are. They are also viewer dependent. The reason is basically that a double line is not a double line but a thicker black line with a somewhat thinner while line on top. The arrow heads have additional, viewer dependent problems. There is not too much one can do at this point.

Comment: Don't worry +1...Is there somebody that can solved the problem between two packages?

Comment: @Sebastiano I think in some years from now viewers will get even better, computers faster, and new decorations in Ti*k*Z or a successor will solve this problem, either in LaTeX or a successor thereof.

Answer (score 0):

Following [Schrödinger's cat's suggestion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/537593/49039), I designed an arrowhead very similar to the arrowhead of `\to` in `[libertine]newtxmath`  using the command `\pgfdeclarearrow`. In the example, I included an overlay of the custom arrowhead with `\to` in order to compare the two. You can tell that they are very similar, yet not precisely the same.

```
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

% Declaration of the new arrowhead
\pgfdeclarearrow{
name = newtxlibertine-right-style,
setup code = {
% The different end values:
\pgfarrowssettipend{0pt}
\pgfarrowssetlineend{-.3pt}
\pgfarrowssetvisualbackend{-0.85pt}
\pgfarrowssetbackend{-2.28pt}
% The hull
\pgfarrowshullpoint{0pt}{0pt}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-1.97pt}{2.04pt}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-2.28pt}{1.71pt}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-2.28pt}{-1.71pt}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-1.97pt}{-2.04pt}}
},
% Drawing of the arrow tip
drawing code = {
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-1.97pt}{2.04pt}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-2.28pt}{1.71pt}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-0.85pt}{0pt}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-2.28pt}{-1.71pt}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-1.97pt}{-2.04pt}}
\pgfpathclose
\pgfusepathqfill
}
}

% Setting this arrowhead as standard for every diagram
% Setting line width that fits the \to arrow
\tikzset{
every picture/.style={>=newtxlibertine-right-style,line width=0.56pt}
}
\tikzcdset{arrow style = tikz}

\begin{document}~\\
\begin{tikzcd}
A\arrow[r]& B
\end{tikzcd}

$A\to B$

$A$\begin{tikzpicture}
\filldraw[help lines,step=1pt,line width=0.1pt]  (0pt,-5pt) grid (10pt,5pt);
%\draw (4.5pt,4.7pt) node {$\to$};
\draw [->] (0,0) -- (9pt,0);
\draw[red] (4.5pt,-0.305pt) node {$\to$};
\end{tikzpicture}$B$

\end{document}
```

[image: Custom arrowhead in the style of newtxmath libertine]